# How to structure following requirements in JAVA classes

Tags: java

Scenario is like this:

1. There is a field in database 'overAllCount' which contains some value.
2. I have to use this variable in many classes I am designing.
3. I want to fetch this 'overAllCount' in one class say 'OverAllCountClass' and use it in all subclasses with its class name like OverAllCountClass.overAllCount. Basically like a static variable.

How can I do it?
My solution is:

```
public Class OverAllCountClass {

    public static int OverAllCount;

     public OverAllCountClass(){

        // Fetch overAllCount from database here and set its value  

       }
 }
```

////////// Use it like this //////////////

```
 public class Usecount {

     public void abc(){

          // BUT IT IS NOT POSSIBLE becuase OverAllCountClass is not yet initialize
         int mycount = OverAllCountClass.overAllCount

      }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use static initialization block, to initialize the static property. static block will run only one time during class load.... so not require to fetch value from database again and again

Comment: @RakeshSoni : Thanks Rakesh . I think this is what I want .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your concern is, the static variable `overAllCount`, might not get initialized and if you want it to get initialized whenever the class `OverAllCountClass` first gets invoked, then you can use [Static initializer blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

```
public class OverAllCountClass {

    public static int overAllCount;

    static {
        overAllCount = fetchOverAllCount();
    }
 }
```

A *static initializer block* is invoked *first time a class gets loaded*. And a class gets first loaded when JVM sees that its been used.

```
public class Usecount {

     public void abc(){
         //When JVM sees that OberAllCountClass is used here, it executes the static block of OverAllCountClass and by the time below statement is executed, overAllCount is initialized
         int mycount = OverAllCountClass.overAllCount
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public Class OverAllCountClass {

    protected int overAllCount; //will allow you to use in subclass too

     public OverAllCountClass(){

        // Fetch overAllCount from database here and set its value  
    }

    public int getOverAllCount(){
       return overAllCount;
    }
 }


public class Usecount {

     //pass the instance of overAllCountInstance to UseCount somehow using constructor or setter
     private OverAllCountClass overAllCountInstance;
     public void abc(){
         int mycount = overAllCountInstance.getOverAllCount();

      }
}
```

*No need* to use `static` over here. Use getter to get the count

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having a *public static variable* which can be modified/abused by other classes. I would provide a specific API which can hide the implementation and do things like *lazy-loading* if needed:

```
public static final Value getValue(){
//evaluate private field
return value;
}
```

This API can be a static method or be a singleton scoped method, depending on use case.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to make `OverAllCountClass` a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

```
public class OverAllCountClass {
    private static final OverAllCountClass instance = new OverAllCountClass();

    private Integer overAllCount = null;

    // make it non-instanciable outside by making the constructor private
    private OverAllCountClass {
    }

    public static OverAllCountClass getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public int getOverAllCount() {
        if (overAllCount = null) {
            //get value from database and assign it
        }

        return overAllCount;
    }
}
```

This has the benefit that to code that accesses `OverAllCountClass` it is transparent wether it's a Singleton or not.  This makes swapping out the implementation easier.